# how to calculate probability?

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm facing difficulty in understanding how they in the book, jumped for (12.13) to (12.14).
what is given is that $b_1$ and $V_2$ are uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$.
I could not post a picture but here are the equations:

(12.12)   $=P(b_1\gt V_2/2)(v_1-b_1)$

(12.13)   $=P(2b_1\gt V_2)(v_1-b_1)$

(12.14)   $=\min\{{2b_1,V_2\}}(v_1-b_1)$

(This is a first price auction symmetric equilibrium problem)

Comment: I really need help in here, someone must know this!!

Answer (score 1):

If all you know is that $b_1$ and $V_2$ are uniform on $[0,1], P(2b_1 \gt V_2)=\frac 34)$  To see this, $2b_1$ is uniform on $[0,2]$.  With chance $\frac 12, 2b_1 \gt 1$ and is certainly greater than $V_2$.  Otherwise, it is uniform on $[0,1]$ the the chance of each being greater is $\frac 12$ by symmetry.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.